# Change font-weight of FontAwesome icons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'd like to make one of the FontAwesome icons a bit less heavy - it's much heavier than the font I am using. This how it looks presently:

[image: heavy remove icon, next to lightweight font]:

Ugly, right? So I've tried resetting the font-weight as follows:

```
.tag .icon-remove  { 
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

The attribute appears to be set correctly in the CSS, but it has no effect - the icon looks just as heavy as before. I've also tried `font-weight: lighter` and `-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px` with no effect.

Is there any way I can make the icon less heavy? The docs say "[Anything you can do with CSS font styles, you can do with Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)" but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: TL;DR: No you can't.

Comment: You can use  `content: "×";` with verdana font for example

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**2018 Update**

Font Awesome 5 now features *light*, *regular* and *solid* variants. The icon featured in this question has the following style under the different variants:

[image: fa-times variants]

A modern answer to this question would be that different variants of the icon can be used to make the icon appear bolder or lighter. The only downside is that if you're already using *solid* you will have to fall back to the original answers here to make those bolder, and likewise if you're using *light* you'd have to do the same to make those lighter.

Font Awesome's [How To Use](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) documentation walks through how to use these variants.

---

**Original Answer**

Font Awesome makes use of the [Private Use region of Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29). For example, this `.icon-remove` you're using is added in using the `::before` pseudo-selector, setting its content to \f00d (`&#xF00D;`):

```css
.icon-remove:before {
    content: "\f00d";
}
```

Font Awesome does only come with one font-weight variant, however browsers will render this as they would render any font with only one variant. If you look closely, the `normal` font-weight isn't as bold as the `bold` font-weight. Unfortunately a normal font weight isn't what you're after.

What you can do however is change its colour to something less dark and reduce its font size to make it stand out a bit less. From your image, the "tags" text appears much lighter than the icon, so I'd suggest using something like:

```
.tag .icon-remove {
    color:#888;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U6LWY/), and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U6LWY/1/) is further proof that this is definitely a font.

Comment: Not only does @JamesDonnelly address the problem at hand but he also offers a solution directly addressing the users end intention. Thanks for the great response!

Comment: so in other words you need to pay for pro icon ;)

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Comment: I'm using pro svg and the icons are not as thick as the legacy font-based library. Solid is still too skinny for doesn't look as good. Is there any way to force some kind of addition bold effect?

Answer (score 141):

Webkit browsers support the ability to add "stroke" to fonts. This bit of style makes fonts look thinner (assuming a white background):

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
```

Example on codepen here: http://codepen.io/mackdoyle/pen/yrgEH
Some people are using SVG for a cross-platform "stroke" solution: http://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/dGIsK

Comment: If you have white font, change the above to: `-webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;` to see the effect. Brilliant ;)

Comment: doesn't work in IE11. in all other browsers - works.

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I like! thanks

Answer (score 30):

Just to help anyone coming to this page. This is an alternate if you are flexible with using some other icon library.

James is correct that you cannot change the font weight however if you are looking for more modern look for icons then you might consider [ionicons](http://ionicons.com/)

It has both ios and android versions for icons.

Comment: Question is about FontAwesome not ionicons

Comment: Yes i know - this is an alternative if someone has the flexibility.

Answer (score 7):

The author appears to have taken a freemium approach to the font library and provides [Black Tie](http://blacktie.io/) to give different weights to the Font-Awesome library.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution I've used to create lighter fontawesome icons, similar to the `webkit-text-stroke` approach but more portable, is to set the color of the icon to the same as the background (or transparent) and use text-shadow to create an outline:

```
.fa-outline-dark-gray {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #999,
            1px -1px 0 #999,
           -1px 1px 0 #999,
            1px 1px 0 #999;
}
```

It doesn't work in ie <10, but at least it's not restricted to webkit browsers.

Comment: I have a whole lot of icons output onto a page and I've just applied this technique. It's not bad overall, it gets tricky with combined/stacked font icons, and things that have been colorised. But if the use case were simple enough, this does lighten the stroke.

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Answer (score 0):

```
.star-light::after {
    content: "\f005";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490