# Want to make font-awesome icons thinner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I was working with font awesome icons but the problem is they have default font weight . i want it a little bit thinner. but its not working

my html code

```
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg fa-5x color-red">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
    </span>
```

my css code

```
    .fa-trophy{
      font-weight:lighter;
     }
```

Comment: i dont' know if possible, but try to add to the font awesome .fa class (the one inside the fontawesome css) the font weight to 100 or 200 and see what happens

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836851/change-font-weight-of-fontawesome-icons

yoe may find something useful

Comment: Add a stroke around the font in the opposite color, this will make it thinner, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949675/1066234

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, it´s not possible to do that using standards (if it is not important in your project you can use the Kiryl Ply suggestion). Font-Awesome comes with just one font-weight variant. There is a new project to solve that problem (not ready yet):

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/232193852/font-awesome-black-tie

you could look for another library with a bit thinner aspect, try "icon font" in Google.

Answer (score 52):

You can fix it in webkit with:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px background-color;
```

Comment: Seems a little hacky, but it does works. Make sure to replace "background-color" with your actual background color. Thanks Kiryl

Comment: fyi, only supported in chrome and android

Comment: This is brilliant, and for the time of this comment, it is supported in Microsoft Edge 15+, Firefox 49+ as well as other webkit browsers, all supporting browsers use `-webki`t prefex, http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke

Comment: Non standard

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke

Comment: It may seam like a "hack" because it isn't solved by fontawesome, but it is solved by css; which is a very relevant use case in any browser. Nice answer. Helped me out.

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Answer (score 4):

```
.yourclass::before{    
content: "\f07a";
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px white;
    color: transparent;
}
```

this did the work for me, change the color to transparent and add a text stroke of your favorite color and you can also change the text stroke to 1px or more if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but hopefully my answer can help someone who wants a thinner circle when stacking two font awesome icons. I spent a lot of time and energy before I stumbled across this [article](http://markheath.net/post/font-awesome-circle-background) which helped me in the right direction. My solution:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
   <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-circle"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

.icon-circle{
color: transparent !important;
border: 5px solid #YourColor;
border-radius: 50%;}
```

When I clean up my code I can probably remove the `!important` tag, but this is how my code looks 5 minutes after I found my solution.

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490