# How to make/render a font-awesome font "thin"?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

**[SSCCE JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/804jeg82/51/)**

I am using [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/angle-right/) and [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/angle-left/) font from font-awesome in my web page. But the less-than and greater-than signs appear really thick. I have given them a size of 90px, because that is how big I want them to be, but not that thick.

The `font-weight` does not seem to work at all.

*Note:* The example contains several other CSS properties since they correspond to my real code.

**So what can I do to get a very thin font here, like the second image below.**

*What I have:*

[image]

*What I want:*

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836851/change-font-weight-of-fontawesome-icons

Comment: @kranthi117 I see! Can you suggest some other service like that where I could get the thinner font?

Comment: you could add in your `.left-arrow` and  `.right-arrow`  classes  `-webkit-text-stroke: 4px grey; ` and then play around with the px and the correct color of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it's possible. Because it is a font that uses images. The proportion of the images can not be changed (to be thinner, for example).
The images can be enlarged and narrowed simply because it is scalable.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried:

```
.fa-angle-right {
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, `font-weight` is not working at all, with any value. You can check in the Fiddle.