# How to control font-weight with font-awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to change the weight of my font-awesome font (I'm using version 5, but not the Pro version), and for some reason I can't do it.

I already tried:

```
.icon {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0%
}
```

Is there any way to get the "light" version of the icons without paying the Pro version?

This:
[Change font-weight of FontAwesome icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836851/change-font-weight-of-fontawesome-icons)

Don't solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: There is only one weight for the font-awesome fonts so you cannot alter them. The only way would be to use the SVG + JS version or the SVG sprites. See https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font-weight of FontAwesome icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836851/change-font-weight-of-fontawesome-icons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website states that solid fonts have `font-weight` of **900** and brands fonts have `font-weight` of **400** you don't have any control over `font-weight`.

[Font Awesome - getting started](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started)

Comment: font awesome 5 does not allow it

Comment: even if you change it wont have any effect

Comment: thats what i am saying it's not allowed and it wont work.. you have look for another font icons which provides that version

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I was looking for this also and realized that you just have to add this after the font awesome css.

```
 <style>
  .fa, .fas {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
</style>
```